# External Link with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm totally new with React and I'm facing off a problem with an external Link. I would like to use it for a redirection to GitHub every time I click on the icon but actually the new window is not showing up instead I have this URL :
http://localhost:3000/https://github.com. I don't why it is not working because with my footer i have almost the same code and it is working well. If you have solutions for that it will be much appreciated ! Thank you very much

Carditem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function CardItem(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <li className='cards__item'>
        <Link className='cards__item__link' >
          <figure className='cards__item__pic-wrap' data-category={props.label}>
         
            <img
              className='cards__item__img'
              alt='Travel '
              src={props.src}
            />
           
          </figure>
          <div className='cards__item__info'>
            <h5 className='cards__item__text'>{props.text}</h5>
            <Link 
            class='social-icon-card-github'
            to={{ pathname: "https://github.com" }}
            <i class='fab fa-github' /> 
            </Link>
          
          </div>
          
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}
export default CardItem;
```

Footer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Footer.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Footer() {
  return (
    <div className='footer-container'>
      
      <section class='social-media'>
        <div class='social-media-wrap'>
          
          <small class='website-rights'>© 2020</small>
          <div class='social-icons'>

            <Link
              class='social-icon-link github'
              to={{ pathname: "https://github.com" }}
              target='_blank'
              aria-label='Github'
            >
              <i class='fab fa-github' />
            </Link>
            <Link
              class='social-icon-link codepen'
              to={{ pathname: "https://codepen.io" }}
              target='_blank'
              aria-label='Codepen'
            >
              <i class='fab fa-codepen' />
            </Link>
            <Link
              class='social-icon-link Linkedin'
              to={{ pathname: "https://www.linkedin.com" }}
              target='_blank'
              aria-label='LinkedIn'
            >
              <i class='fab fa-linkedin' />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Don't use `Link`, use `a href` - [reference](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147)

Comment: I found this solution while searching and it worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69869226/16278681

Answer (score 9):

react-router is used for internal navigation, if you want to navigate outside of your website you should use an a element:

```
        <a
          class='social-icon-link github'
          href="https://github.com"
          target='_blank'
          rel="noopener"
          aria-label='Github'
        >
          <i class='fab fa-github' />
        </a>
```

The `rel="noopener"` is a good security practice: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

Comment: Hi @Axnyff , Thanks for your answer but the problem is that href is not working <Link className='cards__item__link' > </Link> outside it is fine

Comment: Your external link is inside a <Link> ?

Comment: I copy and past your element at the place of mine in CardItem.js but there is another Link  that wrap up everything including img, h5 and your element. if the <a >tags is included between <Link className='cards__item__link' > </Link> it's not working but if I put it  outside the <li> </li> then redirection work.

Comment: Ah ok, it's probably a bad practice to have nested links like this. You can probably get away with this if you add a `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation();}`

Comment: I find an easier solution  by simply changing the <Link> for a <div> and now the redirection work !

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call external links with `react-router-dom`'s `Link` component. Try the following:

```
<a href="https://github.com">Link</a>
```

You can also open links in a new tab:

```
<a href="https://github.com" target="_blank">Link in new tab</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for  your advices @mleister but the fact is the href inside the  <Link className='cards__item__link' > </Link> is not working but if put it outside, the redirection is happening.

Comment: Don't wrap the href inside a Link, just use the a tag

Answer (score 2):

If your URL coming from the API's you can use like that

```
<Link to={{ pathname:`https://${strFacebook}`}} target="_blank"> Facebook </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have understood.
The main fact is you need to use  tag instead of  tag.
Side by side you have to endure that the url must start with **"https:"** else it will always redirect to localhost:........
for example, if you write `<a href="github.com">Github</a>` it will not work. You have to write `<a href="https://github.com">Gitbuh</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use tags such as `<a>` to redirect to external sites. `react-router` is used for internal navigation. If you really wish to do it in this way, you can set the path in the `to` parameter.

```js
<Link to="https://www.linkedin.com/in/zichenghuang915/">
```

Note that you must prepend the URL with `https://`, or else `react-router` will just append your string to the root URL.

Answer (score -3):

the link element is not closed

```
<Link 
        class='social-icon-card-github'
        to={{ pathname: "https://github.com" }}>
        <i class='fab fa-github' /> 
        </Link>
```