# Unable to make Ant button open an external link in a new tab in React and NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, routes, next.js

I have an Ant button set up like this:

```
<Button
                              style={{ borderRadius: '0.5rem' }}
                              type="default"
                              target="_blank"
                              onClick={() => {
                                window.location.assign(
                                  value.upComing[0].jitsiUrl,
                                );
                              }}
                            >
                              Join your Jitsi appointment
                            </Button>
```

where value.upComing[0].jitsiUrl is a URL string. However, when I actually press on the button, it appends the URL to the end of the current path, like this:

[image]

Additionally, it does not open in a new tab. Thus, I would like to know how to make it so that when the button is pressed, the URL is successfully opened in a new tab. I have tried using the "href" attribute with the "target = '_blank' " attribute, and while this opens in a new tab, the URL still appends to the end of the current path. (And for some reason, the string is undefined when I try that).

(Note: the App uses React and NextJS)

Comment: Try adding the protocol to the URL string, e.g. `https://meet.jit.si/rdANP7KICSlm_heka`.

Comment: Yes, this did end up working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a few days since I solved this, so sorry for the late update. It turns out, I had to append my URL with "https://", as it wasn't saved like that in the database. After that, it worked.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but it should exist a better solution then adding more verification to a compenent that should already manage this kind of cases.